# Como criar uma tabela(vazia) a partir de uma seleção de outras tabelas?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

**EXEMPLO**:

Tenho duas tabelas :

- **tabela1** : com duas colunas **id_produto**, **nome_produto**;
- **tabela2** : com três colunas **id_marca**, **id_produto**, **nome_marca**

Gostaria de criar uma **tabela3** a partir de uma seleção da **tabela1** e **tabela2** com apenas as colunas **id_produto**, **nome_produto** e **nome_marca**.

```
CREATE TABLE tabela3 IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT p.id_produto, p.nome_produto, m.nome_marca
    FROM tabela1 p
    JOIN tabela2 m 
    ON p.id_produto = m.id_produto
)
```

Fazendo desse jeito consigo obter **quase** o que pretendo, so que a **tabela3** é criada já preenchida com os dados das tabelas **1** e **2**. O que eu gostaria de obter é uma tabela fazia com a **estrutura** baseada na seleção das outras tabelas.

Tentei de uma outra maneira ( usando o **LIKE**):

```
CREATE TABLE tabela3 IF NOT EXISTS LIKE(
   SELECT p.id_produto, p.nome_produto, m.nome_marca
    FROM tabela1 p
    JOIN tabela2 m 
    ON p.id_produto = m.id_produto
)
```

Obtive um belo erro de syntaxe SQL.

Existe uma outra maneira de fazer isso ?

Comment: Olá André, o que você está querendo obter com um `CREATE TABLE ... SELECT` nesse caso? É só para não repetir O `DLL` das colunas? Acho que acaba sendo mais fácil criar as tabelas diretamente se você não precisa dos dados.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly totalmente de acordo, complementei a resposta com a sintaxe do SHOW CREATE TABLE caso ele opte por essa via, que me parece mais sensata.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly na verdade a **tabela3** sera criada automaticamente assim que eu lançar o meu script, portanto optei pelo `CREATE TABLE ... SELECT` visto que a criacão da tabela pretendida não sera manual.  **Essa solução foi escolhida de acordo a necessidade**, se não o mais viavel seria o que você sugeriu.

Comment: Me parece uma necessidade artificial, pq pra fazer o select você já tem que saber de antemão a estrutura de qq forma, ou seja, dá na mesma. De qq maneira, deixei as 2 soluções, a limpa sem ser automática, e a automática conforme pedido.

Comment: @Bacco sim você esta certo, mais sera complicado eu ter que explica-lo todos os motivos pela qual optei por este caminho... Simplificando, na verdade eu estou a criar um sistema de historico somente pra essas duas tabelas e nas colunas especificas, no entato tenho de copiar a estrutura dessas colunas tal como elas são... Ja tive supresas negativas criando manualmente as tabelas !

Comment: @AndréPKA sim, já deixei alternativas para vc ver a que mais serve pro seu caso. Só quis reforçar o ponto, pq realmente o automático pode te dar algumas surpresas nos casos em que as tabelas tenham nomes similares de campo, etc. Claro que só vc que sabe realmente o que precisa, por isso acho legal expor alternativas, independente da que eu ache melhor. Teste o que eu propus, e qq coisa deixe um comentário se precisar de algum ajuste.

Comment: @Bacco Valeu mano... A gente ta nessa !!

Comment: Opá, quis dizer *DDL* no comentário acima. O @Bacco já estressou bem o ponto sobre alternativas e o motivo dessa não ser uma boa idéia. Eu gostaria de acrescentar um outro, essa sintáxe se torna bastante estranha caso você venha precisar de *constraints* e coisas do gênero. Como o bacco mencionou, você pode usar `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, `SHOW COLUMNS` e informações do `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` se precisar automatizar o processo com um script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Para fazer "automático":

Crie uma condição que não retorne registros:

```
CREATE TABLE tabela3 (
    SELECT p.id_produto   AS id_produto,
           p.nome_produto AS nome_produto,
           m.nome_marca   AS nome_marca
    FROM tabela1 p, tabela2 m
    WHERE false
);
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4efd6f3/1)**.

- O `WHERE false` faz com que o procedimento não retorne nenuma linha, deixando a nova tabela vazia.
- Não se esqueça de usar ALIAS nos casos onde possa ter ambiguidade de nomes, para evitar problemas.
- Como você não está usando os dados, pode simplificar o JOIN desta maneira:

  ```
  FROM tabela1 p, tabela2 m
  ```

  (não tem problema nenhum manter como está o original também, ambos  funcionam)

### Se quiser ter mais controle sobre o procedimento

Você pode executar este comando nas tabelas, e recuperar os tipos das colunas para refazer o `CREATE` manualmente, quase sempre é preferível:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE meubanco.minhatabela;
```

Aí você copia as definições da coluna que quiser, na ordem que for melhor para sua nova tabela, e ajusta tudo que for necessário.

Answer (score 0):

Com o TOP 0 só terá a definição das colunas, sem seus valores.

```
SELECT TOP 0 p.id_produto, p.nome_produto, m.nome_marca INTO tabela3 
FROM tabela1 p
INNER JOIN tabela2 m 
ON p.id_produto = m.id_produto
```

Caso queira verificar se a tabela existe insira o condicional a seguir

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tabela3') IS NULL
BEGIN
   SELECT TOP 0 p.id_produto, p.nome_produto, m.nome_marca INTO tabela3 
   FROM tabela1 p
   INNER JOIN tabela2 m 
   ON p.id_produto = m.id_produto
END
```

Comment: A idéia é boa, mas TOP e OBJECT_ID não funcionam no MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Olá!
Bem, eu sei que o código está feião. Mas num teste rápido aqui, isso cumpriu com o que você busca. Veja, caso a quantidade de campos for maior que os três atuais, então é melhor refatorar.
Abraço!

```
CREATE TABLE tabela3 (
 SELECT p.id_produto, p.nome_produto, m.nome_marca
 FROM tabela1 p
 JOIN tabela2 m 
 ON p.id_produto = m.id_produto
 WHERE p.id_produto IS NULL 
  AND p.nome_produto IS NULL
  AND m.nome_marca IS NULL
);
```

Mas veja a segunda forma, realmente correta informada por nosso amigo LS_dev nos comentários, utilizando (WHERE FALSE)

```
CREATE TABLE tabela3 (
SELECT p.id_produto, p.nome_produto, m.nome_marca
FROM tabela1 p
JOIN tabela2 m 
ON p.id_produto = m.id_produto
WHERE FALSE);
```

Comment: Faltam 2 `IS NULL`. De qualquer forma, o `SELECT` irá devolver linhas em que a condição se verifique. Não é garantido que essas linhas não existam!

Comment: Olá LS_dev, valeu pela informação. Mas acabei de testar com as tabelas preenchidas e rolou.

Comment: A  Condição IS NULL pode sim ser definada por último, neste caso após separar cada campo com a condição AND. De qualquer forma, agradeço a observação.

Comment: Teste com `INSERT INTO tabela1 VALUES(1, 1); INSERT INTO tabela2 VALUES(1, NULL);`. A tabela3 não será criada vazia. Esta solução funcionará se fizer `WHERE FALSE;`

Comment: Vou testar aqui

Comment: LS_dev, fiz o teste aqui e a terceira tabela(tabela3) está sendo montada com os 3 campo e com nenhuma tupla. De acordo com o que o nosso colega busca. Não deu erro.

Comment: O MySQL retornou um conjunto vazio (ex. zero registros). (Consulta levou 0.0003 segundos.)
id_produto nome_produto nome_marca

Comment: Tipo de servidor: MariaDB
Versão do servidor: 10.1.18-MariaDB-1~jessie - mariadb.org binary distribution

Comment: Desculpe insistir, mas não está correcto. http://rextester.com/RWGNY81139 `IS NULL` só está aplicado a `nome_marca`. De qualquer forma, o mais correto seria eliminar de todo a possibilidade de a condição ser verdadeira, daí `WHERE FALSE`.

Comment: LS_dev, você tem razão. Irei editar a resposta. Obrigado!